# Sitecore license for JSS

Tags: jss, licensing

I have to do a POC in Sitecore JSS. I understand Sitecore 8.2 license can be used with Sitecore 9.1 but I need to know if I can work with JSS using my existing Sitecore 8.2 license?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if your license is a JSS-enabled license, open your license.xml in a text editor and search for `Sitecore.JSS`, if it's found, you can use JSS.

Comment: Thanks, I can find the same in my current license file <name>Sitecore.JSS</name> Cheers :)